# get back AS file information after overwriting

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I did just something really fucXXing stupid.
I wrote over my actionscript code, saved it and closed it. now i cant get the information back.
Do you have any tips. Been writing for 2 weeks on it. Iknoow i should backup it :)

Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working with flash builder you can try right click on the file to open context menu - then "Team" and then something like "local history" (sorry my flash builder isn't on english). Then open old version of the file.

In other IDEs try to find out if there's a similar file history option.